# Bootstrap form label and field not in line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to get the text in line with te input field.
The text is also on the wrong side of it. Should text first, then input field.

Am I misinterpreting the div structure?
[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="datum" class="col-md-2-form-label">Datum toolbox</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datum" name="datum">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `"col-md-2-form-label"`.  Did you want `"col-md-2  form-label"`?

Comment: That was easy... Thanks!